# Error in if (num_colors <256) when importing csv files?

Tags: r, csv, colors

I recently updated to R 4.03 and since doing so I have had difficulty uploading csv files in R studio. This is true whether trying to import with code or when manually importing using the tab Environment -> "Import Dataset." The error message I receive is "Error in if (num_colors < 256) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed."

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(readr) 
df <- read_csv("df.csv")

Error in if (num_colors < 256) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`
```

I thought this may have something to do with the package "crayon" but loading this library does not seem to make a difference.

Furthermore, when I save "df.csv" as an excel file "df.xlsx" I am able to load the dataset without issue using the following code

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel(df.xlsx)
```

I don't encounter this problem when using R 4.0.2 on a different machine, so I suspect this issue may be related to the upgrade.

Any insights are appreciated.

**Update**:
Newish R user and I appreciate everyone's interest in this question. I believe the session is clean. Per Ben's request:

```
find("read_csv")
```

[1] "package:readr"

```
sessionInfo()
```

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.3  crayon_1.4.1 readxl_1.3.1 plyr_1.8.6   readr_1.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.6       rstudioapi_0.13  magrittr_2.0.1   hms_1.0.0        tidyselect_1.1.0 lattice_0.20-41  R6_2.5.0         rlang_0.4.10     fansi_0.4.2
[10] tools_4.0.3      grid_4.0.3       utf8_1.1.4       DBI_1.1.1        cli_2.3.0        ellipsis_0.3.1   assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_3.0.5     lifecycle_0.2.0
[19] Matrix_1.2-18    purrr_0.3.4      vctrs_0.3.6      glue_1.4.2       compiler_4.0.3   pillar_1.4.7     cellranger_1.1.0 generics_0.1.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3

> 

Comment: This is in a clean session, right? Can we see results of `find("read_csv")` and `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: same error noted here: https://www.biostars.org/p/489945/ . `packageVersion("crayon")` ?  Try re-installing the `crayon` package?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest updating RStudio to the latest version as well as R.

That did the trick for me.

**Edit**

In view of Ben's request below.

R version: 4.0.4;
RStudio version: 1.4.1103

Comment: could you please edit your answer to include your RStudio version and your R version?